# "get_int_parms" not available for .Fortran() for package "glmnet"

Tags: r, fortran, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am trying to fit a simple lasso model with the latest glmnet package.

I have read in a csv-file and have all my data stored as a "list" or matrix.

I tried to follow this guide for the implementation:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/ridge-regression-and-the-lasso/

But when I run:

```
lasso.mod <- glmnet(b[,2:22], b$power, alpha=1)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in .Fortran("get_int_parms", fdev = double(1), eps = double(1), 
>   :    "get_int_parms" not available for .Fortran() for package "glmnet"

In my input:

`B` is just a matrix with 23 columns and around 100000 rows. The first colunmn is what I want to have as my explanatory variable. I googled around a bit but did not find so much on this type of error. Anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: Does the code from the blog post work for you? What ist the output of `.Fortran("get_int_parms", PACKAGE = "glmnet")` and `packageVersion("glmnet")`? What OS do you use?

Comment: Cannot try since I don't have the data that the blog works. I have copied it and used my own data frames and then adjusted the names. 

Not sure, I am completely unfamiliar with .Fortran...

I use windows 7.

Comment: The dataset used in that blog post is build in, c.f. `?swiss`.  Even if you are unfamiliar with `.Fortan` (c.f. `?.Fortran`) you could just run the command in R ...

Answer (score 2):

Recently got the same error.

I reinstalled the glmnet package and everything worked fine.