# Error when running glmnet through Rscript and nohup

Tags: r, nohup, rscript, glmnet

When creating a predictive model with the `glmnet` package in R, I observed the same error mentioned both here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381618/get-int-parms-not-available-for-fortran-for-package-glmnet). But the proposed solution of reinstalling the `glmnet` package does not fix my problem.

**Minimal working example `my_glmnet_script.R`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript --vanilla

# load libraries
library(methods)
library(glmnet)
library(doParallel)

# create toy model
n = 100 
p = 250 
x = matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)
y = matrix(rnorm(n), n, 1)

# number of parallel cores to use
ncores = 4 
registerDoParallel(ncores)

# print this before glmnet throws error
print(sessionInfo())

# fit model
my.glmnet = cv.glmnet(x=x, y=y, grouped=FALSE, parallel=TRUE, nfolds=n)
cat("end script.\n")
```

**My command:**

```
nohup Rscript my_glmnet_script.R > nohup.out 2> nohup.err &
```

**Output file `nohup.out`:**

> ```
> R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
> Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
>
> Matrix products: default
> BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
> [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
> [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
> [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
> [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] parallel  methods   stats     graphics  grDevices utils datasets 
> [8] base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] doParallel_1.0.11 iterators_1.0.8   glmnet_2.0-16 foreach_1.4.3    
> [5] Matrix_1.2-12    
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] compiler_3.4.3   codetools_0.2-15 grid_3.4.3       lattice_0.20-35
> ```

**Error file `nohup.err`:**

> ```
> nohup: ignoring input
> Loading required package: Matrix
> Loading required package: foreach
> Loaded glmnet 2.0-16
>
> Loading required package: iterators
> Loading required package: parallel
> Error in .Fortran("get_int_parms", fdev = double(1), eps = double(1), : "get_int_parms" not available for .Fortran() for package "glmnet"
> Calls: cv.glmnet -> glmnet -> glmnet.control -> .Fortran
> Execution halted
> ```

Output from `Rscript --version`:

> R scripting front-end version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)

The confusing part is that the following command works just fine:

```
Rscript my_glmnet_script.R
```

It also runs fine if I call `source("my_glmnet_script.R")` from within R.

Why does  `nohup` behave badly with `glmnet` and `Rscript`? Is there an R package that I could load that would make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `nohup` is probably not the problem.

From my question, the R version from `nohup` is R v3.4.3, while `Rscript --version` returns R v3.3.3. This is because my `$PATH` points to my personal R (v3.3.3) before using the system-wide R (v3.4.3).

Why does the system-wide R get called? The answer lies in the script hash-bang:

`#!/usr/bin/env Rscript --vanilla`

To wit, calling `/usr/bin/env Rscript --version` yields

> R scripting front-end version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)

and the system-wide R looks for `glmnet` in my personal (v3.3.3) library, the first entry of `.libPaths()`, which was never compiled for 3.4.3:

```
/usr/bin/Rscript -e ".libPaths(.libPaths()[2:3]); library('glmnet')"
```

> Error in library("glmnet") : there is no package called ‘glmnet’

Moral of story: stay organized when multiple R versions are installed on your server!